# Xamarin iOS Build - FirebaseCrash executable appearing inside package contents

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin

I am receiving this error from Apple when submitting to the App Store:

> ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'XXXXX.app/FirebaseCrash' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles.

I currently have outdated packages that rely on Xamarin.Build.Download v0.4.11. I do not have this "FirebaseCrash" exe appear in my app's package contents when I build before I update anything. This only happens when I update all my packages to the latest, which then require Xamarin.Build.Download v0.10.0.

How can I stop MSBuild from throwing this FirebaseCrash executable into my app's package contents? Is this some post-build action I have to do now to remove it, because this exe never showed up before?

These are all the related packages in my app:

- Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Analytics
- Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core
- Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Crashlytics
- Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CrashReporting
- Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Installations
- Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.InstanceID
- Xamarin.Google.iOS.Anayltics
- Xamarin.Google.iOS.TagManager

Answer (score 1):

Evidently the cause was the "Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CrashReporting" package. I was able to safely remove this package, since the functionality moved to the "Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Crashlytics" package.

Comment: Thank you, in every forum / issues on github nobody mentioned this!